# Refresh Data on single sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to Refresh Data on a single sheet. That is to re-import the External Data text file.

I can do this by clicking on the Refresh Data button (on the Data tab), but I want to find the equivalent in VBA.

Comment: You should be able to right-click and find a refresh option, hidden under Edit Query I think

Comment: Not sure you understood my question or I may have understood your answer... But in Excel VBA there doesn't seem to a **Refresh** sub routine for the Worksheet object (only a **RefreshAll** sub for the Workbook object). I did not use a query to get the External Data, I simply imported a text file. I want to put a button on the sheet that lets the user re-import the text file without having to re-import them all (I have other such imported text files on other sheets)

Comment: Indeed, this is not an available option for disconnected imports. You could create a shortcut to call your refresh macro though, or put a refresh button on the worksheet.

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do... Is there a way to simulate a click on that Refresh Data button from within VBA, or do I have to write a whole sub that will effectively import the text?

Comment: if you use External Data from Text, you'll have to write the sub. If you use From Other sources \ MS Query \ and use the Text driver, you can just right-click and refresh, or call the refresh method of query in your vba code.

Answer (score 1):

```
ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Item(1).Refresh
```